# Running Time Complexity vs. Space Complexity in sorting

Tags: algorithm, asymptotic-complexity

I'm pretty new to algorithms and I have some questions. Let's say I have a sorting algorithm that sorts data at O(n^2), running time complexity. This could be selection sort for example. Now, let's say that instead of using selection sort I use a HashTable which reduces the running time to O(n).

- **Does the additional space complexity have an effect on the running time analysis?**
- **When stating the answer how do I define the relationship between these two?**
- **Or are they completely different altogether?**

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You can sort in O(n) with an hash table?

Comment: the sorting with a hash table actually costs O(n*logS), in which S is the space of numbers to sort. People think that's a constant number just because it's usually a very small number. (like 32 when we sort 32-bit integers)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your analysis is focused on the **time complexity** of the algorith, you should focus only on the **time** each operation costs.

If your analysis is focused on the **time and space complexity** of the algorith, you should focus on the **time** each operation costs, and on the **space** cost of your data structures.

Since **time and space are different resources**, time and space analysis should be done separately .

---

That said, there's the key notion of **[Space - time tradeoff](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Space%E2%80%93time_tradeoff).**  In short, one can modify a given algorithm trading time with space, and vice versa.

**For example you can reduce the time complexity by introducing some complex-and-space-consuming-but-fast data structure**. This would be an example of time -> space tradeoff, because we speed up our algorithm at the cost of increased memory use.

Answer (score 0):

If it's running time analysis in theoretical algorithm theory, space complexity does not have effect on the running time complexity. Because when we talk about the time complexity, we are talking about the time complexity of a program on a
 **[Turing Machine](http://www.cs.odu.edu/~toida/nerzic/390teched/tm/definitions.html) , which has infinite memory**.

The space and time trade-off thing is only for applications. See @Haile's post for reference.